# How to find max value from a output consisting of multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My input is like this :

```
{car:10,bus:100, lorry:12,truck:89}
{car :12,bus:19,lorry:1,truck:90}
{car:14,bus:22,lorry:44,truck:0}
```

I want to print the maximum values for each of the keys across all the dictionaries above as  below:

```
{car:14,bus:100,lorry:44,truck:90}
```

Comment: Show your effort

Comment: @kuro- I have done enough effort and I didn't want to confuse people with the steps I did . I think it is Ok to say that you don't know the answer.

Comment: @Julien- You are a genius in the wrong place .

Comment: can you please show me your data properly , is your data list of dictionary?

Comment: @ammy - Right on , It is a list of dictionaries

Comment: @sudeepmathew *"I have done enough effort and I didn't want to confuse people with the steps I did"* No. It is expected that you show you have made an effort, rather than just expect someone to write some code for you

Comment: @SiHa: How about let people do what they feel appropriate instead of acting like a moderator ? . It is good that there are people in this forum who doesn't feel full of themselves and who actually know their stuff.

Comment: @sudeepmathew Whatever - you carry on, but you should understand that flagging and voting are tools to enable to community to collectively moderate content. You have been down-voted because your question *"Does not show any research effort..."* (as in the tooltip). Tip: In life, you will find that a less combative attitude is generally more effective at getting help from people. Anyway, you have your answer - enjoy, and have a great day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module along with a `comprehension` like this example:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

a = [{'bus': 100, 'car': 10, 'lorry': 12, 'truck': 89},
 {'bus': 19, 'car': 12, 'lorry': 1, 'truck': 90},
 {'bus': 22, 'car': 14, 'lorry': 44, 'truck': 0}]

b = chain.from_iterable(k.items() for k in a)
final = dict(max(list(v), key=lambda x: x[1]) for _, v in groupby(sorted(b, key=lambda x:x[0]), lambda x: x[0]))

print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'bus': 100, 'car': 14, 'lorry': 44, 'truck': 90}
```

Comment: Is there a python function to convert the individual dictionaries that I mentioned to a single list like you did  ? . My input data is rather a group consisting of individual dictionaries.

Comment: You can do `new_list = [my_dict1, my_dict2, my_dict3]`

Comment: Thanks , let me try this.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = {}
for(key,val), (key,val2),(key,val3) in zip(l[0].items(), l[1].items(), l[2].items()):
    result[key] = max(val,val2,val3)
```

you will get:

```
>>> result
{'lorry': 44, 'bus': 100, 'car': 14, 'truck': 90}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
d = {'a':5, 'b':6, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a':6, 'b':7, 'c': 3}
d3 = {'a':7, 'b':1, 'c': 5}

new_dict = {}
for(k,v), (k,v2),(k,v3) in zip(d.items(), d2.items(), d3.items()):
    new_dict[k] = max(v,v2,v3)
```

Output:

```
new_dict= {'a': 7, 'b': 7, 'c': 5}
```